# What does "balance sheet banks" mean in this context?

Tags: banking

Can anybody explain them for me, please?
Moran said that his firm's value proposition is in their distribution. He said Mischler **plays a complimentary role** to the "**balance sheet banks**," mainly because they are well-positioned to serve underserved middle markets.

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/mischler-on-snap-ipo-2017-2

Comment: http://www.wallstreetoasis.com/forums/what-is-a-balance-sheet-bank may be a useful reference article.

Answer (score 1):

The balance sheet for a bank is the list of assets and liabilities that the bank directly is responsible for.  This would be things like loans the bank issues and accounts with the bank.

Banks can make both "balance sheet" loans, meaning a loan that says on the balance sheet - one the bank gains the profits from but holds the risks for also.  They can also make "off balance sheet" loans, meaning they securitize the loan (sell it off, such as the mortgage backed securities).

Most major banks, i.e. Chase, Citibank, etc., could be called "balance sheet" banks because at least some portion of their lending comes from their balance sheet.  Not 100% by any means, they participate in the security swaps extensively just like everyone does, but they do at least some normal, boring lending just as you would explain a bank to a five year old.  Bank takes in deposits from account holders, loans that money out to people who want to buy homes or start businesses.

However, some (particularly smaller) firms don't work this way - they don't take responsibility for the money or the loans.  They instead "manage assets" or some similar term.

I think of it like the difference between Wal-Mart and a consignment store.  Wal-Mart buys things from its distributors, and sells them, taking the risk (of the item not selling) and the reward (of the profit from selling) to itself.  On the other hand, a consignment store takes on neither: it takes a flat fee to host your items in its store, but takes no risk (you own the items) nor the majority of the profit.

In this case, Mischler Financial Group is not a bank per se - they don't have accounts; they manage funds, instead.  Note the following statement on [their Services page](http://mischlerfinancial.com/mischler-capital-market-services-disabled-veteran-owned-broker-dealer/debt-capital-market-fixed-income_minority_broker_dealer/) for example:

> Mischler Financial Group holds no risk positions and no unwanted inventory of securities, which preserves the integrity of our capital and assures our clients that we will be able to obtain bids and offers for them regardless of adverse market conditions.

They're not taking your money and then making their own investments; they're advising you how to invest your money, or they're helping do it for you, but it's your money going out and your risk (and reward).